# Why can't I see any results in the Go To navigation popup?

Tags: visual-studio

When I search for files or symbols via Edit -> Go To there are no results. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to resize it. Enter something into the search that will have results. Then move the cursor from the text edit to the bar just underneath it until you get the resize cursor. Then resize the results window.